# SQL ORDER BY with CASE with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, union, case

Running PostgreSQL (7.4 and 8.x) and I thought this was working but now I'm getting errors.

I can run the queries separately and it works just fine, but if I UNION or UNION ALL it throws an error.

This errors out: (Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  column "Field1" does not exist ... ORDER BY CASE "Field1" W...)

```
SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
"Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
FROM "TableName" 
WHERE condition
AND other_condition
UNION ALL
SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
"Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
FROM "TableName" 
WHERE yet_another_condition
AND yet_another_other_condition
ORDER BY CASE "Field1"
    WHEN 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

This works:

```
SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
"Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
FROM "TableName" 
WHERE yet_another_condition
AND yet_another_other_condition
ORDER BY CASE "Field1"
    WHEN 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

And this works as well:

```
SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
"Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
FROM "TableName" 
WHERE condition
AND other_condition
ORDER BY CASE "Field1"
    WHEN 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

and if I leave off the ORDER BY and just use the UNION or UNION ALL it works as well.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put everything in another SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
  "Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
  FROM "TableName" 
  WHERE condition
  AND other_condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
  "Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
  FROM "TableName" 
  WHERE yet_another_condition
  AND yet_another_other_condition
) As A
ORDER BY CASE field_1
    WHEN 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

or, better, use the alias in ORDER BY, as it is passed at the end of the UNION:

```
  SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
  "Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
  FROM "TableName" 
  WHERE condition
  AND other_condition
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "Field1" AS field_1, "Field2" AS field_2,
  "Field3" AS field_3, "Field4" AS field_4
  FROM "TableName" 
  WHERE yet_another_condition
  AND yet_another_other_condition
  ORDER BY CASE field_1
    WHEN 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END
```

Comment: @Phill: In the first place, I didn't noticed you used the field name and not the alias...:)

Answer (score 1):

The first one does not work because you should do

```
ORDER BY CASE field_1
```

The `"Field1"`  is only available in a single subquery, and after you make the UNION with a common alias, you cannot refer to that column as `"Field1"` any more.

Comment: +1 for helping with the answer. I did this but I get this error: ERROR:  ORDER BY on a UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT result must be on one of the result columns