# Append the query result to the first query result at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Suppose i have query 1 and query 2 in postgresql then i want a combine result of both the queries such that first i will get result set of query 1 and at the end of result set 1, result set 2 should get added.
Suppose query 1 result set has 10 records and query 2 has 5 records then order should be
1 to 10 -- first result set
11 to 15 -- second result set

Please suggest as i am confused because my 1st query contains order by for 5 types of data.

Comment: Ref:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427381/sql-order-by-with-case-with-union-all

Answer (score 2):

You can combine results with `+`

```
resultC = resultA + resultB
```