# postgres `order by` argument type

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

What is the argument type for the `order by` clause in Postgresql?

I came across a very strange behaviour (using Postgresql 9.5). Namely, the query

```
select * from unnest(array[1,4,3,2]) as x order by 1;
```

produces `1,2,3,4` as expected. However the query

```
select * from unnest(array[1,4,3,2]) as x order by 1::int;
```

produces `1,4,3,2`, which seems strange. Similarly, whenever I replace `1::int` with whatever function (e.g. `greatest(0,1)`) or even `case` operator, the results are unordered (on the contrary to [what I would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427381/sql-order-by-with-case-with-union-all)).

So which type should an argument of `order by` have, and how do I get the expected behaviour?

Comment: What **is** the expected behaviour? Add some sample data and the expected output to your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is expected ([and documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html)) behaviour:

> *A `sort_expression` can also be the column label or number of an output column*

So the expression:

```
order by 1
```

sorts by the first column of the result set (as defined by the SQL standard)

However the expression:

```
order by 1::int
```

sorts by the constant value `1`, it's essentially the same as:

```
order by 'foo'
```

By using a constant value for the `order by` all rows have the same sort value and thus aren't really sorted.

To sort by an expression, just use that:

```
order by 
    case 
       when some_column = 'foo' then 1
       when some_column = 'bar' then 2
       else 3
    end
```

The above sorts the result based on the *result* of the `case` expression.

Comment: OK, but then how do I plug in e.g. case operator?

Comment: @overdawn: see my edit, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I've tried `select * from unnest(array[1,4,3,2]) as x order by case when true then 1 end;` but it doesn't work (actually this is why I asked the question;))

Comment: `case when true then 1 end` does not make any sense, it's a really complicated way to obfuscate the constant number `1` What is the **real** problem you are trying solve? Maybe you should edit your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Actually I have a function with an integer argument which indicates the column to be used in the order by clause. But I don't see the problem with `case when true then 1 end` - it is just a (brutal) simplification of your example. And it doesn't work for me. If it worked, my problem would be solved.

Comment: @overdawn You mean `order by my_func(column_number int)`?

Comment: "case operator"? Suspect you meant a "case expression". The case expression `case when true then 1 end` is the equivalent of `case when 1 then 1 end` or `case when 'constant' then 'constant' end` in effect it leaves your result unsorted.  `case when column >= value then 1 else 0 end` might be a more practical example perhaps.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Something like this:

create temp table my_data (
  id serial,
  val text
);

insert into my_data(id, val)
values (default, 'a'), (default, 'c'), (default, 'd'), (default, 'b');

create function fetch_my_data(col int)
returns setof my_data as
$$
 select * from my_data
 order by col
$$ language sql;

select * from fetch_my_data(2);

Comment: ok I put that into http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94cf4/1 but I don't follow I'm afraid. What do you expect the result to be? (that's in your head but not mine) & What does that have to do with a case expression?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I have a function with an integer argument which indicates the column to be used in the order by clause.

In a case when all columns are of the same type, this can work: :

```
SELECT ....
ORDER BY 
  CASE function_to_get_a_column_number()
    WHEN 1 THEN column1
    WHEN 2 THEN column2
    .....
    WHEN 1235 THEN column1235
END
```

If columns are of different types, you can try:

```
SELECT ....
ORDER BY 
  CASE function_to_get_a_column_number()
    WHEN 1 THEN column1::varchar
    WHEN 2 THEN column2::varchar
    .....
    WHEN 1235 THEN column1235::varchar
END
```

But these "workarounds" are horrible. You need some other approach than the function returning a column number. 
Maybe a dynamic SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that dynamic SQL (thanks @kordirko and the others for the hints) is the best solution to the problem I originally had in mind:

```
create temp table my_data (
  id serial,
  val text
);

insert into my_data(id, val)
values (default, 'a'), (default, 'c'), (default, 'd'), (default, 'b');

create function fetch_my_data(col text)
returns setof my_data as
$f$
begin
 return query execute $$
   select * from my_data
   order by $$|| quote_ident(col);
end
$f$ language plpgsql;

select * from fetch_my_data('val'); -- order by val
select * from fetch_my_data('id'); -- order by id
```

In the beginning I thought this could be achieved using case expression in the argument of the `order by` clause - the [`sort_expression`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html). And here comes the tricky part which confused me: when `sort_expression` is **a kind of identifier** (name of a column or a number of a column), the corresponding column is used when ordering the results. But when `sort_expression` is **some value**, we actually order the results using that value itself (computed for each row). This is @a_horse_with_no_name's answer rephrased.

So when I queried `... order by 1::int`, in a way I have assigned value 1 to each row and then tried to sort an array of ones, which clearly is useless.

There are [some workarounds without dynamic queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function), but they require writing more code and do not seem to have any significant advantages.